# How do I fix class not found in custom extension after upgrade?

Tags: drupal, extension

I have just upgraded civicrm to 4.6.11 and am getting a Class Not Found error.

```
Fatal error: Class 'CJT_Page_EmrJournaltracking_JournalControls' not found in ... CRM/Core/Invoke.php
```

The class is in the system

```
 web/sites/all/modules/custom/civicrm/extensions/net.interlated.emrjournaltracking/CJT/Page/EmrJournaltracking/JournalControls.php
```

and defined as follows

```
require_once 'CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php';

class CJT_Page_EmrJournaltracking_JournalControls extends CRM_Core_Page_Basic {
```

The source for this extension is available at https://github.com/jrobens/civicrm-extension-emrjournaltracking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed by changing all the classes to be in the CRM namespace. e.g.

```
class CJT_Page_EmrJournaltracking_JournalControls
```

Becomes

```
class CRM_Page_EmrJournaltracking_JournalControls
```

Disable and re-enable the extension to load the changes.